# Spring Boot | localhost: 8080 404 error page displayed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot Maven project, however my RequestMapping, as well as localhost:8080 return a 404 error page. I think the issue is with how my packages are setup, but I've tried solutions in multiple questions, and I still cant get around the error page. Could you guys point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this issue? Perhaps I need to add the Component annotation above my Main class? But I've tried this solution, and the error still persists.

Here is my package structure:

```
 /src/main/java
      ControllerLayer
           UsersController.java
      DataAccessLayer
           UsersDAL.java
      ServiceLayer
           UsersService.java
      Main
           Main.java
```

Main.java:

```
  @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { 
  "/src/main/java/ControllerLayer", "/src/main/java/DataAccessLayer", 
  "/src/main/java/ServiceLayer" })
  public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
     }
  }
```

UsersController.java:

```
 import Entities.Users;
 import ServiceLayer.UsersService;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/users")
 public class UsersController {

      @Autowired
      private UsersService usersService;

      @RequestMapping(value = 
      "/create/{userId}/{userPassword}/{userAge}/{userEmail}"
      + "/{userFirstName}/{userlastName}", method = 
      RequestMethod.POST)

      public void createUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId, 
      @PathVariable("userPassword")String userPassword, 
      @PathVariable("userAge")int userAge, 
      @PathVariable("userEmail")String userEmail,
      @PathVariable("userFirstName")String userFirstName, 
      @PathVariable("userLastName")String userLastName) {

           usersService.createUser(new Users(userId, userPassword, 
           userAge, userEmail, userFirstName, userLastName));
      }
   }
```

UserService.java

```
 import DataAccessLayer.UsersDAL;
 import Entities.Users;

 @Service
 public class UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDAL usersDAL;

    public void createUser(Users user) {
         usersDAL.createUser(user);
    }
 }
```

pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>xProjectAlpha</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.htech.xProjectAlpha</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
      </parent>

      <properties>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.9.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
           </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
           <plugins>
                <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>

 </project>
```

Comment: You need to remove `/src/main/java/` from `scanBasePackages` and then what is the url you are trying?

Comment: If i remove the /src/main/java, Spring throws an UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersService'. The URL i was using was just localhost:8080/users

Comment: Can you add your package names to your classes above?

Comment: Also, add the code for `UsersService` class

Comment: Code for UsersService class added

Comment: package names? and url?

Comment: Second for the input url.

Comment: The input URL i'm using is just localhost:8080/users, but localhost:8080 is also throwing the 404 error page. Also, added the Import packages to my classes above. For the input URL, do I need to use localhost:8080/projectname/users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is sent, then a response shall be returned. In your case, you didn't send any content with the response and that's why you get 404 error (page not found).

Answer (score 1):

In main.java, try:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { 
  "ControllerLayer", "DataAccessLayer", 
  "ServiceLayer" })
```

Your package names shouldn't include the root path in the project.

Comment: If i remove the /src/main/java, Spring throws an UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersService'

Comment: @Jered Hart It's picking up your controllers now. Something is wrong with usersService in usersController - follow the stack trace and post another question. Try also adding "Main" to scanBasePacakges.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to have spring boot Application class in root package and have all other classes in package structure below that package .You don't have to worry about component scan  as an example

```
package com.igt.customer;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomerApplication.class, args);
    }

     @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
            return args -> {

                System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

                String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
                Arrays.sort(beanNames);
                for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                    System.out.println(beanName);
                }

            };
        }
}
```

Controller class

```
package com.igt.customer.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    @RequestMapping("/employee")
    public String employee() {
        return "Greetings from Sam!";
    }
}
```

running the application (go to the directory of your application on cmd )

**E:\MongoDb\New folder\customer>mvn install -U -e**

you should see this in the end if its fine

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.686 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-16T16:39:57+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

run the jar file

**E:\MongoDb\New folder\customer\target>java -jar customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

accessing the application

http://localhost:8080/employee

**Notice application name is not required in URL**

P.S i have written extra detail here as i have experienced if you are new to spring boot  building and running the application is a challenge , in my application i had created a rest controller in the same package as the Application class with RequestMapping "/" as i was getting 404 error  , Please see the link below as a reference

[spring boot application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be simply solved if you remove the main package of the main.java class.

The new structure will be:

```
/src/main/java
      Main.java
      ControllerLayer
           UsersController.java
      DataAccessLayer
           UsersDAL.java
      ServiceLayer
           UsersService.java
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `Spring` boot application, there is no need to scan the base packages manually because all the configurations are embedded in a single annotation `@SpringBootApplication`.  Please refer to [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

I don't understand how the base packages are initially configured.  Can someone please explain this?

For example, if your base package looks like:

`com.example.myapp.SpringApplication`

... it means your application takes base packages as `com.example.myapp`.  So if you can create all `Controllers`, `Service`, `Repository` under `com.example.myapp` in the sense it will load your `Controllers`, `Service`, `Repository` easily or else it can't able to load.  This is because `springbootapplication` intially sets the base packages and loads whatever java classes are inside the base package.  So because of this you get a `404` error in the browser as well as in `postman`. So try to match with base package.